# MainActivity is not an enclosing class

Tags: android, android-studio, parse-platform

I'm using parse and I'm a beginner to android development.  I need to start MainActivity when click the login_button. But when I add my MainActivity class to the parse login builder in LoginSampleActivity it shows, 'MainActivity is not an enclosing class' error.

This is my MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
    implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

This is LoginSampleActivity

```
public class LoginSampleActivity extends Activity{
```

And this is my button click event

```
loginOrLogoutButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (currentUser != null) {
                ParseUser.logOut();
                currentUser = null;
                showProfileLoggedOut();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"Login",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                ParseLoginBuilder loginBuilder = new ParseLoginBuilder(
                        MainActivity.this);
                startActivityForResult(loginBuilder.build(), LOGIN_REQUEST);
            }
        }
    });
```

This is my Manifest file

```
<activity
        android:name=".LoginSampleActivity"
        android:launchMode="singleTop">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_main"
        android:launchMode="singleTop"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">

    </activity>
```

Thanks

Comment: What is your intent? Could you post it? (loginBuilder.build() return)

Answer (score 3):

its not about a name "MainActivity or FirstActivity". Check the manifest file.

```
    <activity
        android:name=".first"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.**LAUNCHER**" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

1. in activity tag , category ".LAUNCHER" defines the first page to start.
2. Check your manifest, which activity has category "Launcher".
3. Create login button on that activity and create another class to pass.

Comment: `<activity
            android:name=".LoginSampleActivity"
            android:launchMode="singleTop">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_main"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">

        </activity>`

Comment: Thanks for the reply. This is my manifest file. I have created the login button in that activity. Please help

Comment: 1. create a new class name "Second"         2. extends AppcompatActivity    3. create xml file and design the layout for that second page.    4. in "Second.java"  insert Oncreate code().     5. inside oncreate --> "setcontentview(">>xml file name<<")".  6. now your activity is set..   7. register on manifest.     8. open manifest .xml   9. below </activity>  create new <actvity android:name:".Second" />  10. in your loginSampleactivity  -> inside button click "Intent inn = new Intent(LoginSampleActivity.this, Second.class);   startActtivity(inn)"

Answer (score 1):

Problem is in the following line:

```
ParseLoginBuilder loginBuilder = new ParseLoginBuilder(
                    MainActivity.this);
```

Instead of *MainActivity.this* I suppose You'd like to write *MainActivity.class*.

Compilation error says that *LoginSampleActivity* does not extends *MainActivity* so you can't use *MainActivity.this* inside of *LoginSampleActivity*.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your answers. I found the solution for my problem. The problem was in the ParseLoginBuilder class. Therefore I created a new class called MainActivityBuider and added the build() method to that class. Now it is working. Thank you again for your answers. @Marek @Rathna